# pip installs only __pycache__ files

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip

When I pip install anything, it installs only the **pycache** folders but no .py  files at all. The installation reports installed successfully but apparently I cannot import the packages I installed.

I installed requests package, and want to

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
```

but it reports

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests.adapters'
```

So I go to check where the packages is installed and found that there are only the **pycache** folder and the files inside exist.

Comment: When you run `pip install <package>` again after the succesfull installation, doe it report the library already installed in the location that you are checking?

Comment: @FlyingTeller , It says Requirement already satisfied

Comment: Can you 1) do `import requests`? 2) verify that the location that is listed after `Requirement already satisfied` is the one that you have also checked?

Comment: You can try `--force-reinstall` to make `pip` try to install even if already there. Which python is installed (i.e., not which version of python, but how did you install it)? Where is the directory "where the packages [are] installed"? Has `pip` worked for you before?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, I get the location by import requests and vars(requests).

Comment: @AndrewJaffe Yes `pip` worked before. I installed python with pyenv, so I just tried to update pyenv. And somehow, now it can install correctly, though all the packages are installed in a different folder.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe but then I find although the installation succeed, I cannot import the package at all. I decide to uninstall Python completely and start over.

Comment: It sounds like the `pip` you are using isn't actually correct for the python (or virtual environment) you are in.